# Why don't I have the Guru badge?

Tags: discussion, support

[Guru](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru) badge:

> Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. This badge can be awarded
>   multiple times.

On the [Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8140/605) question, I have 43 votes. I should have the Guru badge, but I do not. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Self acceptance answers do not appear to be eligible for the Guru badge. While I can't immediately find an official (SE employee) confirmation of this, it was accepted as answer here:

[Why haven't I earned the Guru badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120491/why-havent-i-earned-the-guru-badge)